# How to wrap a website in Genexus mobile application

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

i would like to have a Genexus mobile application include a website within the boundaries of the mobile application.  Similar to using an iframe in a web application.  The basic flow it the user launches the mobile application on their device, then after account creation and information gathering, selects from a list of list of sites.  once selected the site will be within the boundaries of the mobile application (like an iframe).  I am using the using the Genexus 3 eval for android devices and cannot find an example within the guides.  Please note that there is other functionality before the navigation to a website.  This app is not just a switchboard.  The website has years worth of functionality built in already and is very mobile friendly.  i need an account creation and surveying mobile app as a new front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented something similar using [Component Domain](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?16186).

Basically:

1. Define a SD Panel
2. Define a variable based on Component domain (e.g. &Component)
3. Assign the site URL including HTTP to the variable in an event
   Example: 
   Event "Start"
   &Component="http://www.google.com"
   endevent
4. Include the variable into the SD Panel form.
5. Customize how the control will be displayed (e.g. set the variable properties AutoGrow=True and ReadOnly=True, set the main table Columns Style and Rows Style properties to 100%)

In your example perhaps you could define an attribute to store the site's URLs and to use a grid showing these URLs in a SD Panel.